# How to get Java Date object from Camel XPathBuilder XPath expression?

Tags: xpath, apache-camel

I've got a program that uses Camel's XPathBuilder to create and evaluate xpath expressions in a processor bean.

I've created the object

```
XPathBuilder xpath = XPathBuilder.xpath( "path/to/dateElement", java.util.Date );
```

and execute it

```
Object obj = xpath.evaluate( exchange, Object.class );
```

however when I log the value of `obj` it is null. If I request it as a String, it returns the XML date format string as I would expect.

Does XPathBuilder not support conversion to java.util.Date? (I can't see a list of supported output classes in the documentation anywhere.)

I tried casting the xpath expression explicitly to `xs:dateTime`, but that gave me an exception saying it couldn't convert the expression to a nodeList.

(It works fine when I want a java.lang.Long or java.lang.Double instead of java.util.Date)

How do I get the Xpath to return a Date object?

Thanks! Screwtape.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `XPathBuilder`, only conversion to `Number`, `String`, `Boolean`, `Node` and `NodeList` is supported out-of-the-box. If you want to support other types, you need to implement custom [Type Converter](http://camel.apache.org/type-converter.html).

```
import org.apache.camel.Converter;
import org.apache.camel.TypeConverters;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class XmlDateTypeConverters implements TypeConverters {

    @Converter
    public Date convertNodeToDate(Node node) throws ParseException {
        return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX")
                .parse(node.getTextContent());
    }

    @Converter(allowNull = true)
    public Date convertNodeListToDate(NodeList nodeList) throws ParseException {
        if (nodeList.getLength()==0){
            return null;
        }
        return convertNodeToDate(nodeList.item(0));
    }
}
```

And registration of `XmlDateTypeConverters` to CamelContext depends on your preferences, with Java DSL it looks like this:

`getContext().getTypeConverterRegistry().addTypeConverters(new XmlDateTypeConverters())`

In Spring, is `TypeConverter` discovered automatically, if it is bean.